# Triggering of spinnaker pipeline from gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have added following gitlab parameters in igor.yml in service-settings directory in .hal
gitlab:
  baseUrl: "https://gitlab.com"
  privateToken: ''
  commitDisplayLength: 8

But the pipeline is still not triggering in spinnaker when a small change is committed in gitlab develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you should use ./profiles/igore-local.yml to configure your Gitlab connection.